# contentsOfDirectoryAtURL not listing all files in iCloud synced folder - iOS9

Tags: ios9, file-handling

I have an app which synchronises all created or changed files in a sub folder the App's document directory. That worked ok until iOS9. Now the app can "see" only the files it created itself, but files which have been created on other devices or my Mac will not be listed by contentsOfDirectoryAtURL. The files which should be shown are actually encrypted data files. I noticed that the type of the files created by the app on the local device is "TextEdit-Document" whereas the other unlisted files are correctly typed as "data".

Here's a snipped of the code I have used since many years inside this app, but now the array dirContent does not contain the names of all files, but error is nil:

```
BOOL retVal = NO ;

NSURL *cloudFileUrl = [self getDataLocation] ;

cloudFileUrl = [cloudFileUrl URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"iSecretData" isDirectory:YES] ;


NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *dirContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:cloudFileUrl includingPropertiesForKeys:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NSURLNameKey, nil] options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:&error];

// directory does not exist
if (error.code == 260)
{
    error = nil ;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:cloudFileUrl withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error] ;
}
```

I use the same code on the Mac OS X version of the App and still works fine even with El Capitan. So I suspect an iOS9 bug.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I had to put the following in front of the call to contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:cloudFileUrl error:&error] ;

if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR Loading %@", cloudFileUrl) ;
}

NSArray *dirContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:cloudFileUrl includingPropertiesForKeys:[[NSArray alloc] initWith
```

calling startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL did the trick. Interestingly enough I had this call in in previous versions but then it caused trouble and I took it out.